# Is their a faster way to copy .vhd and .vhdx files?

Tags: windows, ssd, powershell, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

Right now I am using Item-Copy in powershell to copy a 20GB .vhdx file. The file sits on an SSD with hardly any services running. One would expect the copy time to take ~2 minutes. The copy took about 30 minutes if I remember right.

Is there a way to do fast copying or figure out why it took so long to copy? The Hyper-V VM was also shutdown too.

I would like to keep the solution to where it can work within PowerShell if at all possible for 3rd party apps so if they can be CLI based that is great.

EDIT:
I decided to do a manual file copy. Started off well over 100MBs then it dropped to 10~30MBs. I'm just curious. **Does Windows Server 2012 R2 have a feature or service that might limit operations in order to prevent abuse?**

SSD model for those interested:

```
SanDisk SD6SB1M-128G-1006
```

[image]

Comment: So the new file is being created on the SSD?  How much memory does the server have?

Comment: I would try [FastCopy](https://ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en) to see if it can speed up the copying.

Comment: @Ramhound 16GBs and yes SSD both ways. More then half the RAM is free to be used to.

Comment: @benJephunneh I'll give FastCopy a try and see how that works.

Comment: What’s the SSD’s make and model?

Comment: Ttat is about 11MB/sec. If it was from USB2 to another USB2 drive then that is perfectly normal. If not please add the configuration, SSD models and if they are SLC/MLC or TLC.

Comment: @DanielB hennes added

Comment: Mixed IO is going to be worst-case. ( http://ssd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/8226/SanDisk-SD6SB1M128G1022I ) says "Avg. 4K-64Thread Mixed IO Speed 33.1MB/s". Not sure how synthetic that particular test is.

Comment: @Yorik good call. I may just switch out the SSD for a samsung drive tonight. First time working with a SanDisk SSD.

Comment: with respect to FastCopy, I think xcopy has an unbuffered switch, but FastCopy claims to have a same-disk method to read to a vary large buffer and then pause to write, side-stepping the mixed-IO problem I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Mixed I/O and a consumer drive actually was the problem.

Setup a 2 SSD. One to hold templates and the other to hold running machines. Copying from one drive to another fixed the I/O dropping and gave back SSD performance.